# PassportJS Local Strategy not working Withh MongoDB

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, passport.js

I'm trying to get a handle on user authentication with PassportJS, and I cannot get it to work my database setup.

I'm using MongoDB *without* Mongoose, and I can't get the LocalStrategy module to work.

Hopefully my database queries aren't too cumbersome to read.

**Local Strategy:**

```
passport.use(new LocalStrategy(
function(username, password, done) {
//Fire up database
mongo.connect("mongodb://localhost:27017/formulas", function(e, db) {
  if (e) {return next(e);}
  var col = db.collection("users");
  //Do a database query to find a record by username
      col.findOne({"username": username}, function(err, user){
        if (err) { return done(err);}
        if(!user) {
          return done(null, false, { message: "Please check your log in credentials." });
        }
        //if it exists call done() object with user information
        bcrypt.compare(password, user.password, function(err, res){
          if (err) throw err;
          if (res == true) {
            return done(null, {username: username, password: password});
          } else {
            return done(null, false, { message: "Invalid password."});
          }
        });
      });
    });
  }));
```

I call `passport.authenticate()` like this:

```
router.post('/login',
passport.authenticate('local', {successRedirect:'/', failureRedirect:'/about',failureFlash: false}),
function(req, res){
  console.log(req.body);
  console.log(req.user);
  console.log("The user was logged");
});
```

`SerializeUser` and `deserializeUser` look like this:

```
passport.serializeUser(function(user, done) {
  done(null, user.username);
});

passport.deserializeUser(function(id, done) {
  mongo.connect("mongodb://localhost:27017/formulas", function(e, db){
  if (e) {return next(e);}
  var col = db.collection("users");
  col.findOne({"username": id}, function(err, user){
    done(err, {"username": id});
  });
});
});
```

When I call `app.post(/login)` I'm taken directly to `/about` and nothing is logged to the console so I'm not quite sure what's going wrong.

Advice on what to fix or how to troubleshoot is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly when u serialize user object , then in deserialize also whole user object must be passed.
Consider the example below.

For routes :

```
router.post('/login', function(req, res, next) {
  passport.authenticate('local', function(err, user, info) {
    if (err) { return next(err); }
    if (!user) { return res.redirect('/login'); }
    req.logIn(user, function(err) {
        if (err) { return next(err); }
        req.session.user = req.user;
        return res.redirect('/home');
    });
  })(req, res, next);
});
```

For passport.js , place the localstrategy and passport in same folder

```
var passport = require('passport'),
session = require('express-session');
var local = require('./localstrategy.js');
module.exports = function (app) {
  app.use(session({
    secret: 'Site visit',
    resave: true,
    saveUninitialized: true,
    cookie: { secure: false }
  }));
  app.use(passport.initialize());
  app.use(passport.session());
  passport.serializeUser(function(user, done){
    done(null, user);
 });
 passport.deserializeUser(function(user, done){
    done(null, user);
 });
 local();
};
```

For local strategy :

```
'use strict';
var  passport = require('passport'),
local = require('passport-local').Strategy;
var user;
// path where the db.js is placed
var db = require('./../db.js');
var ObjectId = db.getObjectID();
var bcrypt = require('bcrypt');

module.exports = function(){
   passport.use(new local({
    usernameField : 'username',
    passwordField : 'password'
   }, function(username, password, done){
     var collection = db.getDb().collection('users');
     collection.findOne({
        username: username,
     }, function (err, result) {
        if(result == null){
            cb(null, false);
        }else {
          bcrypt.compare(password, result.password, function (err, passRes) {
              if (passRes == true) {
                user = user;
                done(err, user);
               }else{
                  done(null, false, { message : 'Invalid Password'});
               }    
            });
        }
    });
  }));
};
```